# Optimization of a global click counter widget, setinterval issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

A button on my website, when clicked, calls AJAX to increment a database value by 1. The result is shown beside the button and works as expected. I decided to incorporate a setInterval refresh on part of the code; naturally this is the part that's causing some issues.

I'm not sure how big of an issue this is, but when I'm browsing the page with the Element Inspector I get thousands of errors--all the same error:

GET [my website] net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

It also seems like while this implementation does work part of the time the way I would expect it to, it breaks pretty quickly when I browse my site on my phone to test how it performs in real-time.

I think this might be because of the interval request:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#clickButton").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "update_click_count.php",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#count").text(response);
                }
            });
        });

        // Fetch initial click count on page load
        setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "get_click_count.php",
                type: "GET",
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#count").text(response);
                }
            }, 2000);
        });
        });
</script>
```

Is there a better way I should set this up, or is this the best possible way to do it? If I remove the interval function, the number of clicks only gets updated upon a page refresh, and I want it to update in real time, so people can see it go up no matter where they are in the world.

Comment: Are you SURE that's what your current code says?  If you had made the interval `2` instead of `2000`, I might expect that.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yep, it's `2000`. And it's specifically mentioning `/get_click_count.php` as being the offending resource hog, which explains why sometimes the click counter works, and sometimes it lags pretty badly.

Comment: _"Is there a better way I should set this up, or is this the best possible way to do it?"_ - you will find answers to that in numerous similar discussions about such problems with self-written "chat" systems. The solution is to use a push instead of a pull mechanism, implemented for example via web sockets.